# VarChar conversion to Decimal

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have some records in my database with the following format, eg: 04567.123 
The datatype is VarChar.
So when I access them by my C# app I need to sum a number to the last three, like "04567.124" but I am having troubles with this. I use the following code to try to convert the value and then +1

```
using (SqlDataReader read1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read1.Read())
                {
                    string num1 = (read1["NumeroDossier"].ToString());
                    decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1 + 1);
                    textBox10.Text = ndos.ToString();
                }
            }
```

But it gives me an error, a format error and I can't figure it out :\
Can someone helo me? Many thanks!

EDIT1:

```
string num1 = (read1["NumeroDossier"].ToString());
                    decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    decimal total = ndos += (0.001);
                    textBox10.Text = total.ToString();
```

SOLUTION (Many thanks to Habib):

```
 using (SqlDataReader read1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read1.Read())
                {
                    string num1 = (read1["NumeroDossier"].ToString());
                    decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    decimal total = ndos += 0.001M;
                    textBox10.Text = total.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `num1 + 1`? num1 is still a string.

Comment: I think the problem is `string` to `decimal`. Your `num1 + 1` is `04567.1231`? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I've changem it now to string num1 = (read1["NumeroDossier"].ToString());
                        decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1);
                        decimal numdossier = (ndos + 1);
                        textBox10.Text = ndos.ToString();
But the problem stays on

Comment: @SonerGönül my `num1+1` should be `04567.124`

Comment: @Reznor13 Should be? Then you need convert your `04567.123` to `decimal` and add `0.001` not `1`. Since you using `string + int` in your `Convert.ToDecimal`, it works as `string + int.ToString()`.

Comment: @Reznor13, Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question, including your new code. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Just a heads up that the one you flagged as an answer, and are using will work, but my answer will work and prevent you getting a critical error if num1 contains invalid characters. Try it with num1 = "123a" to see. Mine will treat it as 0 and continue. Really depends if you care about belt and bracers or not? I do.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley, I really appreciate your answer and I really thank you, but the problem that you've exposed will never happen in my solution because I've programmed a lot of rules about the correct way to insert data, and the users will never be able to modify this number `ndos`. It's a sequential number generated and read only. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1 + 1);
```

assuming `num1` is set to `"04567.123"` then adding 1 would return a string `"04567.1231"`, It will not increment the last digit as you assumed.

Still that shouldn't cause conversion error due to format. **I believe you are on a culture which uses a different decimal separator** then `.`. You should do:

```
decimal ndos = Convert.ToDecimal(num1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And you don't need `1` to be added to your number You need `0.001M`

```
ndos += 0.001M; //M for decimal
```

You may also consider [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: @Reznor13, can you explain what is not working, are you getting an exception in parsing or the addition doesn't work ?

Comment: as you can see in my edit, I've made the alters that you gave me! in the `ndos += (0.001)` VStudio give me a error and I can't even do the build "Operator += cannot be applied to operands type 'decimal' and 'double' "

Comment: @Reznor13, that was my mistake, use `ndos += 0.001M;`, I have modified the answer as well

Comment: Many thanks Habib! You saved me! :D
But i'm getting another trouble now, one of my records starts with "00001.002" and when I use this method it only returns me "1.003", removing all the left 0's. I really need the zeros to stay! How can I do that? Many thanks!

Comment: @Reznor13, those additional zeros are part of string, `decimal` type doesn't preserve presentation. You need to convert your decimal to string like `string formatted = ndos.ToString("00000.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

This logic should get you to where you need to be.

I believe the main issue is you weren't converting num1 to a decimal BEFORE adding 1, this will give you a casting error. Also you can't use +1 if you want to add to the end, you can use decimal.Add to add 0.001 instead, as shown.

```
string num1 = "1.123";
decimal ndos = 0;
decimal.TryParse(num1, out ndos);
ndos = decimal.Add(ndos, (decimal)0.001);
```

Comment: How do you know `num1` can be parsed successfully?

Comment: thank you, I've already reached a solution and I'll post it right now :D